Are there non-Euclidean geometries based on invalidating one of Euclid's postulates other than the Fifth?
Hyperbolic and elliptical geometry are the most famous of the non-Euclidean geometries, and both of them derive their principles by omitting Euclid's fifth postulate on parallel lines. Are there non-Euclidean geometries that are based on omitting one of the first four postulates?
I did find another question on the existence of other non-Euclidean geometries, but that question seems to be covering other geometries that also omit the fifth postulate but are not hyperbolic or elliptical.
To be clear, I know I can simply state "Assume a geometry where not all right angles are equal to other right angles but the parallel postulate most assuredly holds", and boom, that's a non-Euclidean geometry that omits the fourth postulate, but I'm looking for a geometrical system where I could actually read articles or textbooks about it, prove theorems in it, work problem sets in it, model it in software, or otherwise do something with it other than simply speculating about its existence.

Projective geometry can be presented in this way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry#Axioms_of_projective_geometry

Keep in mind that Euclid's set of axioms was incomplete and does not meet the modern standards of rigor. Consider asking the same question about Birkhoff's or Hilbert's axioms.

spherical geometry - it does not satisfy the incidence axiom

Consider Axiom 1 : a line can be drawn between 2 Points. Let us be given a Set of $n$ Points $V={v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_n}$. With Axiom 1 , let us draw a line between a Pair of Points $e_1=(v_1,v_2)$. Let us draw more such lines $E={e_1,e_2,e_3,\cdots,e_m}$ using $m$ Pairs of Points. Studying $(V,E)$ is graph theory which is the most basic geometry !
